# "Package XXX does not exist" error after installation of xamarin.Android.support.v7.AppCompat

Tags: xamarin.android, android-support-library

After installing xamarin.Android.support.v7.AppCompat, I get lots of error messages when I try to generate the project.

> package android.support.v4.app does not exist
>
> package android.support.v4.content does not exist
>
> package android.support.v4.view does not exist`...

[image]

Can you help me please

Comment: This error message? Please write it here.

Comment: I have many errors  :                                                                          package android.support.v4.app does not exist ;                                         package android.support.v4.content does not exist ;                                            package android.support.v4.view does not exist ;

Comment: Did you add the component? Does the project have references to the appropriate DLLs?

Comment: Any news about solution?